# Application logs to prometheus

Tags: logging, logstash, prometheus, grafana

We have an application running in Kubernetes (AWS EKS) and are able to log in to the bastion host and able to get the logs of the PODS.

Currently, our application is having problems and we would like to debug the application logs for issues on an hourly basis.

We are able to fetch the logs from the pods when we run the command kubectl get pods **** but it's really a hectic process for us to run each and every time and we are also confused about which log we have to check the errors.

Hence we have planned to gather the logs from the pods to the Prometheus tool.

Do we have any URL's that helps us to grab the logs from a file in the pod to promotheus dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is not correct tool for gathering logs. Its meant for gathering and analysing time-series data, mostly metrics.
You should be looking into setting up ELK stack for your cluster for gathering logs.
https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack [ELK stack][1]

Comment: Hello Kalimba thanks for the response.

The page you have posted is no longer exist. Could you please post the appropriate post that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is for getting and monitoring the metrics it's monitoring tools. For you can use the tools like Graylog, Loki with Grafana dashboard, Cloudwatcch logging AWS, Stackdriver logging GCP.

i would recommend checking out the **Loki** : https://github.com/grafana/loki

You can check out the ELK stack and [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. From Prometheus FAQ page...

https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#how-to-feed-logs-into-prometheus